# Improve code to replaceAll String

Tags: java, string, performance, replace, replaceall

Is there another way to do a lot of 'replaceAll' more efficiently, using as less memory as possible?

```
 public static String cleanWordTags(String source) {

    String copy = source;

    copy = copy.replaceAll("<P style=\"M[^>]*>", "<P>");
    copy = copy.replaceAll("<p style=\"M[^>]*>", "<p>");
    copy = copy.replaceAll("<p style=\"T[^>]*>", "<p>");

    copy = copy.replaceAll("<b style=[^>]*>", "<b>");

    copy = copy.replaceAll("<span class=\"M[^>]*>", "<span>");
    copy = copy.replaceAll("<span style='m[^>]*>", "<span>");
    copy = copy.replaceAll("<span style=\"f[^>]*>", "<span>");
    copy = copy.replaceAll("<span lang[^>]*>", "<span>");
    copy = copy.replaceAll("<span style=\"color[^>]*>", "<span>");
    copy = copy.replaceAll("<span style=\"m[^>]*>", "<span>");
    copy = copy.replaceAll("<span style=\"line[^>]*>", "<span>");
    copy = copy.replaceAll("<span style=\"L[^>]*>", "<span>");
    copy = copy.replaceAll("<span style=\"T[^>]*>", "<span>");
    copy = copy.replaceAll("<span style=\"t[^>]*>", "<span>");

    copy = copy.replaceAll("<br [^>]*>", "<br/>");

    copy = copy.replaceAll("<i style=[^>]*>", "");
    copy = copy.replaceAll("</i>", "");

    copy = copy.replaceAll("<st1:personname[^>]*>", "");
    copy = copy.replaceAll("</st1:personname>", "");

    copy = copy.replaceAll("<st1:metricconverter[^>]*>", "");
    copy = copy.replaceAll("</st1:metricconverter>", "");

    copy = copy.replaceAll("<br[^>]*>", "<br/>");

    copy = copy.replaceAll("<\\W\\Wendif\\W\\W\\W>", "");

    copy = copy.replaceAll("<![^>]*>", "");


    copy = copy.replaceAll("<[vowm]:[^>]*>", "");
    copy = copy.replaceAll("</[vowm]:[^>]*>", ""); //&

    copy = copy.replaceAll("&(amp|lt|gt);", "");
    copy = copy.replaceAll("&nbsp;", "");

    copy = copy.replaceAll("<img width[^>]*>", "");
    copy = copy.replaceAll("<img src=\"file:[^>]*>", "");


    return copy;
}
```

I found I can use StringUtils.replace instead replaceAll, but this only works for strings without regex.

Thanks!!!

New:

I tried with the next code related with comments but takes 5 times more time to replace the same String:

```
 public static String cleanWordTags(String source) {
        String copy = source;

        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        String regex = "";

        regex += "(align=\"left\")";
        regex += "|(<mce:style>)";
        regex += "|(<i>)";
        regex += "|(<i style=[^>]*>)";
        regex += "|(</i>)";
        regex += "|(<st1:personname[^>]*>)";
        regex += "|(</st1:personname>)";
        regex += "|(<st1:metricconverter[^>]*>)";
        regex += "|(</st1:metricconverter>)";
        regex += "|(<\\W\\Wendif\\W\\W\\W>)";
        regex += "|(<![^>]*>)";
        regex += "|(<[vowm]:[^>]*>)";
        regex += "|(</[vowm]:[^>]*>)";
        regex += "|(&(amp|lt|gt);)";
        regex += "|(&nbsp;)";

        regex += "|(<img width[^>]*>)";
        regex += "|(<img src=\"file:[^>]*>)";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        copy = p.matcher(copy.toUpperCase()).replaceAll("");

        regex = "";
        regex += "(<span style=\"t[^>]*>)";
        regex += "|(<span style=\"T[^>]*>)";
        regex += "|(<span style=\"L[^>]*>)";
        regex += "|(<span style=\"line[^>]*>)";
        regex += "|(<span style=\"m[^>]*>)";
        regex += "|(<span style=\"color[^>]*>)";
        regex += "|(<span lang[^>]*>)";
        regex += "|(<span style=\"f[^>]*>)";
        regex += "|(<span style='m[^>]*>)";
        regex += "|(<span class=\"M[^>]*>)";

        p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        copy = p.matcher(copy.toUpperCase()).replaceAll("");

        copy = copy.replaceAll("<br[^>]*>", "<br/>");

        //Sustituir
        //        copy = copy.replaceAll("<p class=[^>]*>", "<p>");
        //  copy = copy.replaceAll("<p align=[^>]*>", "<p>");
        copy = copy.replaceAll("<P style=\"M[^>]*>", "<P>");
        copy = copy.replaceAll("<p style=\"M[^>]*>", "<p>");
        copy = copy.replaceAll("<p style=\"T[^>]*>", "<p>");
        copy = copy.replaceAll("<b style=[^>]*>", "<b>");

        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - t0);

        return copy;
    }
```

Comment: Why not use an HTML parser or something?. Regex + HTML == bad idea.

Comment: The problem is that I have a tinymce, where people writes using the buttons of the component or simply copy&paste from the word, and then the result is used to generate a document, so I need to control the tags from myself.

Comment: [You know parsing HTML with regex is bad / impossible, right?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1156554)

Comment: I´m not parsing, I´m removing tags :P

Comment: Is your major concern memory-consunption or time-consumption? How long are your strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end the only solution I found was to replace all the "replaceAll" without regex for "replace" and  try to generalize the regex.

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you already had a look at **streamflyer** (see: https://code.google.com/p/streamflyer/), though I can't state anything about the performance, but they declare: *"modify characters in a stream - to apply regular expressions, to fix XML documents, whatever you want to do"*

Additionally there is also **streamflyer-regex-fast** (see: https://code.google.com/p/streamflyer-regex-fast/), which *"provides a faster algorithm to match regular expressions on character streams than the algorithm used by streamflyer"*

So if you have your data available as `Reader`, e.g. as `StringReader` you could easily apply the example from the front page to your code, like this:

```
Reader reader = new StringReader("source <p style=\"Memphis\">");
FastRegexModifier modifier = new FastRegexModifier("<P style=\"M[^>]*>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE, "<P>");
ModifyingReader modifyingReader = new ModifyingReader(reader, modifier);
String result = IOUtils.toString(modifyingReader);
```

This has the advantage that you can use the `CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag, which probably reduces the number of rules you need to define. But caution: this may also affect the performance, so you should evaluate both possibilities.

Please report back, if this solution helped to impove your performance.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you want to use regexes, this way is extremely inefficient, as you're searching the whole string again and again (and creating tons of garbage). The proper way is iterating using a `Matcher` in a loop similar to [this one](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/regex/Matcher.java#Matcher.replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29).

Just let you Matcher match everything what could be of interest and branch on what it finds. Your pattern could be something like

```
(?:<(p|b|span|br|i|st1:personname|st1:metricconverter|\\W\\Wendif\\W\\W\\W|!|vowm:|img))[^>]+>)|&(amp|lt|gt|nbsp);
```

It matches more than you want, but you can set replacement to `$0` in such a case. It needs just a single pass through the whole String. You may want to do two passes instead to keep it simpler.